# Script execution time in PHP

Tags: php

I would like to find out script execution of my script. I used the below code.

```
$time_start = microtime(true); 

//Here is a script which is extracting almost 13,000 product using an API

$time_end = microtime(true);    
$execution_time = ($time_end - $time_start)/60;
echo '<b>Total Execution Time:</b> '.$execution_time.' Mins';
```

This script is working well in localhost but it is not working in Production Server. On the other hand if I reduce the product quantity to 4,000 then it is working in production server.

Why is it happening so??

Thanks

**UPDATE**

If I add `echo 'mouse';` at the end of the script then it is also not printing.

Comment: What is your maximum execution time in php.ini?

Comment: My execution time is 500000 second. Thanks

Comment: Insufficient information. "Not working" doesn't help anyone determine what goes wrong. Does the script hang? Does the script exit prematurely? Does the script generate errors? If it isn't generating errors - ensure you enabled error reporting.

Answer (score 1):

It might be the case that your script is facing a time out.

So, please try to add time out limit at the very top of your script file.

```
set_time_limit(0);

$time_start = microtime(true); 

//Here is a script which is extracting almost 13,000 product using an API

$time_end = microtime(true);    
$execution_time = ($time_end - $time_start)/60;
echo '<b>Total Execution Time:</b> '.$execution_time.' Mins';
```

Answer (score 0):

Something is happening before the end of the script. 
Maybe a time out. Make sure that your maximum execution time is high enough.

If your running your script from console check the max execution time with this:

```
php -i | grep max_execution_time
```

Remember that php.ini for console could be different from that used by the web server.

If it's not an execution_time issue try to be verbose in the code block where you extract products. Something like:

```
echo "Extracting product ".$i." (".(microtime(true) . $time_start).")\r\n";
```

This way you can see on your console what's going on and how the time is spent.